# How to connect to Sql Server on localhost from Docker Linux

Tags: docker, connection, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to connect to Sql Server 2017 running on my local machine (in localhost) from a Docker instance using Linux and also running on my local machine.
Here's my connection string

```
Server=10.0.75.1\\MSSQLSERVER2017;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=False;User Id=MyUser;Password=ASecure*Password1;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

Here's the first part of my Docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
ARG source=.
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 51949
EXPOSE 44334
EXPOSE 1433
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000 
COPY $source .
```

The error that I'm current receiving is
`Login failed for user 'MyUser' ...`

I've tried using Sql Server Configuration Manager to set the port, but this had no effect. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

Here's the corrected DockerFile

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 51949

EXPOSE 44334

EXPOSE 1433

Comment: did you ssh on the server and login there with the same user? does it work? mysql -u MyUser MSSQLSERVER2017

Comment: did you try using a full-privileged access user, just to eliminate some access restrictions being the reason?

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't created the user account properly through Security - Logins. Setting the port to 1433 in Sql Server Configuration Manager also helped. Things are working with the corrected DockerFile.